# Is it possible to open jump bar in xcode without mouse?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Jump Bar is very nice tool for navigating inside your file.
[image: jump bar]

Is there any way to open it and navigate there only with keyboard?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I found it!

It's called "Document Items". In documentation it's called "Jump Bar" and in key bindings it's called "document items". Not very clear...
Anyway, the default key binding is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>.

[image: document items]

Comment: Additionally, once the "Jump Bar" is open, you can begin typing to further filter the displayed items.

Answer (score 6):

It is also interesting that Xcode has shortcuts for other selection in jump bars. Try <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> through <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> as well.

Comment: Ctrl+3 actually invokes "Show Next History". You can see all of them (Ctrl+1, Ctrl+2, ... , Ctrl+6) by navigating View -> Standard Editor menu item.