# Make the Document Items list always visible in XCode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

When dealing with large classes containing many methods, it is very helpful to have a quick overview of your file's contents. In XCode 4, the Document Info section of the Jump Bar is where this lives:
(see [Is it possible to open jump bar in xcode without mouse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833614/is-it-possible-to-open-jump-bar-in-xcode-without-mouse))

I have programmed in other environments such as MonoDevelop and Visual Studio which also expose this list as a dockable panel control so it can be always visible. To me, this seems like a no-brainer feature, and hiding it away in a select-box control seems like over-simplification.

I know you can Command-Click the end of the Jump Bar to view the list sorted, and I know you can trigger it by Control-6, but has anyone found or written an extension that can put it as a tab in either the right-side Utilities panel or the left-side Navigator area?

If not, is there a place where these features can be suggested? Do the XCode devs respond to user interface feedback?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that currently. You can file enhancement requests on the [BugReporter website](http://bugreport.apple.com/).